# Usage of "modem"

Tags: meaning

What's the meaning of "modem" in these sentences?

> Neither nationalism nor ethnicity is vanishing as part of an obsolete traditional order. Both are part of a **modem** set of categorical identities invoked by elites. Violence that followed the collapse of Soviet-style communism were not simply throwbacks to some premodem reign of passion, sentiment, and primordial identity.

Comment: Are we sure it isn't 'modern'? Are you reading this in a OCRed text?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on an OCR or typographical error rather than a genuine usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was OCR'd incorrectly.

The full text in question is:

> Neither nationalism nor ethnicity is vanishing as part of an obsolete traditional order. Both are part of a **modern** set of categorical identities invoked by elites and other participants in political and social struggles.

([jstor](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2083387?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents))

P.S. - I'm not sure where the rest of that text is from.

Comment: I did. That's the link i gave as the source in my answer.

Comment: The correct procedure here is to close-vote. OP doesn't bother to link to the source. ELU deals with felicitous questions.

Comment: I was unaware what the correct procedure was. Never come across a question like this. I close-voted afterwards.